# SQL Server Extended Protection fails with .Net 3.5

Tags: .net, sql-server

The scenario is an application built against .NET Framework 3.5 connecting to a SQL Server 2019 on a different machine in the same domain. Both client and server are running Windows Server 2019.

The client fails to connect with the error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Integrated authentication.
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
> at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj)

SQL Server will log:

> SSPI handshake failed with error code 0x80090346, state 46 while establishing a connection with integrated security; the connection has been closed. Reason: The Channel Bindings from this client are missing or do not match the established Transport Layer Security (TLS) Channel. The service might be under attack, or the data provider or client operating system might need to be upgraded to support Extended Protection. Closing the connection. Client's supplied SSPI channel bindings were incorrect.

The connection string is straight forward:

```
Data Source=...; Initial Catalog=...; Integrated Security=true;
```

I have reproduced the error with a minimal console application for testing. When this is build for .Net 3.5, the error occurs. If the same source code is rebuilt for .Net 4.7, it successfully connects.

The SQL Server has both Force Encryption and Extended Protection turned on. If I turn off Extended Protection in SQL Server, then the application built for .Net 3.5 can connect successfully.

I have found this bug report from 2019 *for JDBC* that mentions the same issues:
https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-jdbc/issues/963

**What bothers me** is that despite heavy googling I can't seem to find any documentation, articles or blogs that mention lack of support for SQL Server extended protection on .Net Framework 3.5. I can't even seem to find any other people complaining about the same problem (with .Net 3.5). .NET 3.5 is old, but on the other hand Extended Protection has been available since SQL Server 2008 R2 (released April 2010, about two years after .NET 3.5 was released), so if it is unsupported in .Net 3.5, one would expect that it had been mentioned *somewhere*.

Is anyone able to shed some light on the situation?

Comment: I had literally never heard of Extended Protection before today, despite being well acquainted with SQL Server, so take that as an (admittedly anecdotal) indicator of why this issue may not have gotten the attention you'd expect. :P Per your own mention, .NET 3.5 was released *before* the feature existed, so that it didn't support it out of the box should not be particularly surprising. .NET 4.0 went final around the same time as SQL Server 2008 R2, so new applications would have just targeted that.

Comment: Apparently extended protection support (the general variant) was added to .NET 2.0 (and by extension 3.0 and 3.5) with Service Pack updates ([KB article](https://support.microsoft.com/topic/microsoft-security-advisory-extended-protection-for-authentication-7dd2ee6d-c2e9-3484-2d8e-466261d3f0c7)), but the associated [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2008/dd639324(v=vs.90)) make no mention of `SqlConnection` being retrofitted with the support, so this may have been an oversight (or just a missed window).

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thanks! Per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/connect-to-the-database-engine-using-extended-protection?view=sql-server-ver16, EP is support from Win7 and Windows Server 2008 R2, which is probably why the link you posted about SP updates only mention XP/Vista and Server 2003/2008. It also says "a feature of the network components implemented by the OS". Feels like it implies it is supposed to work regardless of .Net version, on modern OS, especially considering the link with updates.

Comment: It probably does work regardless of the .NET version, provided the TLS layer is actually asked to apply the feature, and presumably older versions of .NET simply don't do this, or they explicitly use old versions of structures when setting up the connection. I'm speculating here because I have no idea how things are actually implemented; TLS/Schannel details tend to be a quagmire navigable only by experts. Fact is that none of this is going to help you somehow make it work with .NET 3.5, as it's not going to be receiving any updates.

Comment: Fact is that none of this is going to help you somehow make it work with .NET 3.5, as it's not going to be receiving any updates. As a workaround, if you *must* get this to work and the application supports arbitrary ADO.NET connections you could try using the ODBC driver instead, as it presumably implements this natively. If it's hard-coded to use `SqlConnection`, the most obvious way to work around it is to run it on .NET 4.x instead, but I'm assuming you're using .NET 3.5 for other reasons. If it's just that it was *built* against 3.5, use `<supportedRuntime>` to override.